# How to Transpose a table with different columns using python

Tags: python, pandas

Here is the initial table as shown below.

| Cust ID | Jan Transaction Fee | Jan Transaction Fee | Jan Product Fee | Jan Product Fee | Feb Transaction Fee | Feb Transaction Fee | Feb Product Fee | Feb Product Fee |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
|  | HKD | USD | HKD | USD | HKD | USD | HKD | USD |
| 100103 | 100 | 20 | 21 | 24 | 215 | 55 | 253 | 25 |
| 100104 | 200 | 30 | 31 | 34 | 315 | 65 | 353 | 35 |

I would like to convert the table from above to the below expected result.

| Cust ID | Period | Type | FX | Price |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 100103 | 202201 | Transaction Fee | HKD | 100 |
| 100103 | 202201 | Transaction Fee | USD | 20 |
| 100103 | 202201 | Product Fee | HKD | 21 |
| 100103 | 202201 | Product Fee | USD | 24 |
| 100103 | 202202 | Transaction Fee | HKD | 215 |
| 100103 | 202202 | Transaction Fee | USD | 55 |
| 100103 | 202202 | Product Fee | HKD | 253 |
| 100103 | 202202 | Product Fee | USD | 25 |
| 100104 | 202201 | Transaction Fee | HKD | 200 |
| 100104 | 202201 | Transaction Fee | USD | 30 |
| 100104 | 202201 | Product Fee | HKD | 31 |
| 100104 | 202201 | Product Fee | USD | 34 |
| 100104 | 202202 | Transaction Fee | HKD | 315 |
| 100104 | 202202 | Transaction Fee | USD | 65 |
| 100104 | 202202 | Product Fee | HKD | 353 |
| 100104 | 202202 | Product Fee | USD | 35 |

My coding on import data is below

```
import pandas as pd 


test=pd.DataFrame({'Cust ID':['','100103','100104'],'Jan Transaction Fee':['HKD',100,200],'Jan Transaction Fee.1':['USD',20,30],\
                  'Jan Product Fee':['HKD',21,31],'Jan Product Fee.1':['USD',24,34],
                  'Feb Transaction Fee':['HKD',215,315],'Feb Transaction Fee.1':['USD',55,65],
                  'Feb Product Fee':['HKD',253,353],'Feb Product Fee.1':['USD',25,35]})

test
```

is there a way to do the expected result with using Python?

Comment: do you really have the '.1' in the input data column names?

Comment: You need pivot. Search for examples on this page.

Comment: @mozway If there is a way to do it without '.1', then ignore the'.1' column name. Thanks so much for your help

Comment: Looks like a multiindex. Pulled from an excel file? How was the data read?

Comment: @sammywemmy Yes, the dataset is pulled from an excel file, but it is confidential. So, i just manipulated the data first and showed a few customer ID as an example

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is a complex reshape.

*NB. I ignored the '.1', removed using `test.columns = test.columns.map(lambda s: s.strip('.1'))`.*

```
df = (test
 .T.set_index(0, append=True).T
 .set_index([('Cust ID', '')])
 .stack()
 .rename_axis(index=['Cust ID', 'FX'], columns='Type')
 .stack()
 .reset_index(name='Price')
)

df[['Period', 'Type']] = df['Type'].str.split(n=1, expand=True)
df['Period'] = pd.to_datetime('2022 '+df['Period']).dt.strftime('%Y%m')
```

output:

```
  Cust ID   FX             Type Price  Period
0  100103  HKD  Transaction Fee   100  202201
1  100103  USD      Product Fee    25  202202
2  100103  USD  Transaction Fee    55  202202
3  100103  USD      Product Fee    24  202201
4  100103  USD  Transaction Fee    20  202201
5  100104  HKD  Transaction Fee   200  202201
6  100104  USD      Product Fee    35  202202
7  100104  USD  Transaction Fee    65  202202
8  100104  USD      Product Fee    34  202201
9  100104  USD  Transaction Fee    30  202201
```